# Planning to triple boot with macOS, Windows, and Linux. Do I use/do Bootcamp before or after installing Linux?

Tags: bootcamp, unix

Pretty much just the title. Does the order that you do it in matter?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.As if you install Linux before using Bootcamp it will actually refuse to install and you will have to do it manually because you changed the partitioning scheme.

1. Bootcamp Windows
2. Install Linux
3. Install a bootmanager so you can get in all OSes as Linux won’t show up in the default GRUB(I advise refind)

Comment: Could I shrink the macOS partition before Bootcamp, or should I do Bootcamp and then shrink the macOS partition?

Comment: @PiAhoy Get the bootcamp working and then partition your Mac drive